# When sending post it returns: stream ended unexpectedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, multipartform-data

When I make a post request with `Content-Type: multipart/form-data`, it returns this error:

> "message": "stream ended unexpectedly"

My code:

```js
const form = new FormData();
if (state.fileCropped) {
  form.append("file", {
    "uri": state.croppedImageFile,
    "name": "image.jpeg",
    "type": "image/jpeg",
  });
}
User.save(form, {
    "Authorization": user.token,
    "Accept": "multipart/form-data",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=2baac014-7974-49dd-ae87-7ce56c36c9e7",
  })
  .then(() => {
    this.context.spinner.hideSpinner();
    this.context.props.history.push("/Users");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.context.spinner.hideSpinner();
    this.context.alert.warn(err.title, err.detail);
  });
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Are you posting a large amount of data such that you might be exceeding a server-side limit?

Comment: Files can be up to 3 mb.

Comment: Could this be the problem?